# Is there a line in space that doesn't intersect any body

Tags: geometry

Say we model our universe as an infinite space with planets that are all spheres of the same size, uniformly distributed through-out with some fixed density.

Is it then true that any infinite line in that space must eventually intersect one of those planets? Does the result depend on the density?

If it matters, I would like to ignore the possibility that due to the random position of each planet, there could theoretically be a line that intersects none of them.

My intuition tells me that the answer is yes because I can imagine examples where the spheres are big enough and dense enough that two "rows" of them would block out the sky with no holes between.
However, I feel like it might be possible that for some low density, the angular size of the planet diminishes just enough (with distance from our origin) that the increased number of planets that are at that distance doesn't compensate for it.

I don't know what to tag this question with. Would appreciate an edit that adds the correct tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless we know exactly where *every* planet is, we cannot answer this question. But what we can say is that if the density is uniform (however small) the probability that any line intersect a planet is $1$.

To see why, subdivide the line into equal segments (say $1000$ km per segment). Then, for each segment, the probability that a planet intersects the segment is some non-zero number $p>0$ that depends on the density. Now, since we repeat the same experiment independently for *infinitely* many segments, the probability that a planet intersects at least one of them is 1.

Comment: Nice! That makes complete sense.